# xfs maintenance mode in redhat 7

Tags: linux, rhel, xfs

In my desktop I installed redhat 7 and after reboot it went to maintenance mode, After entering the password it is not allowing to do a file system scan for root and every time it boots enters to maintenance mode and not allowing to run `xfs_repair` command which is showing error as it is mounted.

```
    # xfs_repair /dev/mapper/rhel-root 
    xfs_repair: /dev/mapper/rhel-root contains a mounted and writable filesystem.

    fatal error -- couldn't initialize XFS library.
```

I tried to execute same command on other file systems which are not mounted and it is working fine.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can at least find out what's wrong by running:

```
xfs_repair -n /dev/mapper/rhel-root
```

`-n` runs xfs_repair in no-modify mode.

If it's complaining about it being mounted *and* writeable, you might want to try re-mounting it read-only (`mount -r -o remount <device>`), but this will probably just come back with '/dev/mapper/rhel-root is busy'.

I'd go with booting from a different medium and running xfs_check from there.

Comment: I tried all these but no luck, XFS always it is saying the file system is mounted even in RO/RW.

Answer (score 1):

Boot from some live medium and perform the `xfs_repair` from there.

Comment: So is there no direct way to get it done

Answer (score 1):

Boot into Emergency mode in which root-fs will be mounted as read-only. For this, add

```
systemd.unit=emergency.target
```

to the kernel parameters in GRUB when booting. After this you would be able to run:

```
xfs_repair -d /dev/mapper/your-root-fs
```